# Adding G729 codec to CSIPSimple

Tags: android, voip

I would like to add G729 codec to CSIPSimple dialelr- the opensource Android SIP app.

Is the g729 codec licensed for using with CSIPSimple? If yes, how much is the charge? Is there any 'maximum simultanious call' limit with the license? I had found a huge license fee for this codec by digium.com. But it seems to be for using with Asterisk.

Is this license fee applicable for the CSIPSimple integration as well?

Answer (score 2):

As of 2017, the G.729 patents have expired. The codec can be used free of charge.

The codec spec and a reference implementation are [freely available](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-G.729-199611-S!AnnA/en).

Answer (score 0):

Integrating is not licence but if you are using on mobile device, you should have licence while selling or distributing it. Regarding integrating you can follow similar steps https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/issues/detail?id=2440